# key names are not known in advance for eval

Tags: redis

The Redis documentation suggests that I specify the key names as parameters for my scripts and read them in the script rather than hard-coding them in the script. This works fine if I know the names when I call the script.

In my case, my key names are stored in a Redis object (a hash), and I need to retrieve some of the hash entries depending on a parameter, and then access these keys atomically.

Does anyone have any thoughts about how make it work in a compliant manner?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. As you mentioned, [Redis EVAL command](http://redis.io/commands/eval) documentation tells:

> all the keys that the script uses should be passed using the KEYS
>   array, in the following way:
>
> > eval "return redis.call('set',KEYS[1](http://redis.io/commands/eval),'bar')" 1 foo OK
>
> The reason for ***passing keys in the proper way*** is that, before EVAL all
>   the Redis commands could be analyzed before execution in order to
>   establish what keys the command will operate on.

But later in the same documentation is written:

> In order for this to be true for EVAL also keys must be explicit. This
>   is useful in many ways, but especially in order to make sure Redis
>   Cluster is able to forward your request to the appropriate cluster
>   node (Redis Cluster is a work in progress, but the scripting feature
>   was designed in order to play well with it). However this rule is not
>   enforced in order to provide the user with opportunities to abuse the
>   Redis single instance configuration, at the cost of writing scripts
>   not compatible with Redis Cluster.

---

So summing up, ***passing keys in the proper way*** is relevant when you are using Redis Cluster, so Redis clustering mechanism knows what data you operate on and thanks to it, it knows where is your data.

When you don't want use Redis Cluster or you achieve clustering in [other way](http://redis.io/topics/partitioning) then ***passing keys in the proper way*** is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Does your atomic access need spawn across the action of reading your key names from the hash, or is it needed only after you've read your key name and are about to use it further?

If you need it all over, then using Lua script read the key name from the hash, store it in a variable and then use it further when fetching data according to that key name. If you only need the atomicity for the second part, first read the key name then use it as a parameter as the Redis documentation suggests for the second part.

Comment: thanks. I need it to be atomic all over. Yes, of course I understand that I need to read my key names from the hash, and then use them. The question is that `EVAL` does not know what key names my script will be using and therefore cannot schedule the script to be evaluated on the right node in a cluster. not that I am using a cluster, but this question is rather theoretical at this point.